# Two states with views views defined for one

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, state

I'm trying to modulise my app using angular-ui-router to define a website with 2 states: main and checkout. The main state should haves multiple "section" tags which im trying to define as ui-view items. I can't tell what's wrong with my routes setup but I get a feeling that the main.html is not being loaded. Any advise on whats wrong with my definition... I could avoid using views for the secions and just use ng-include...

**routes.js**

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/main');
    $stateProvider
        .state('main', {
            url: '/main',
            controller: 'MainCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'templates/main.html',
            views:{
                'home': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/main.home.html'
                },
                'about': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/main.about.html'
                },
                'services': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/main.services.html'
                },
                'shop': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/main.shop.html',
                    controller: 'ShopCtrl'
                }
            }
        })
        .state('checkout', {
            url: '/checkout',
            templateUrl: 'templates/checkout.html',
            controller: 'CheckoutCtrl'
});
```

**index.html**

```
<div ui-view id="app-ui-view"></div>
```

**templates/main.html**

```
<section ui-view="home" id="home"></section>
<section ui-view="about" id="about"></section>
<section ui-view="services" id="services"></section>
<section ui-view="shop" id="shop"></section>
```

Basically the page loads but main or checkout states don't load. How am i nesting things wrong?

Answer (score 0):

By not specifying a parent you map both states to the default ui-view in the `index.html`. So when accessing main state there won't be any templates linked to the default ui-view, the only one present in the existing html.

so the main state should have this definition:

```
.state('main', {
            url: '/main',
            views:{
                '': {
                    controller: 'MainCtrl',
                    templateUrl: 'templates/main.html',
                },
                'home@main': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/main.home.html'
                },
                'about@main': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/main.about.html'
                },
                'services@main': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/main.services.html'
                },
                'shop@main': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/main.shop.html',
                    controller: 'ShopCtrl'
                }
            }
        })
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This only seems to render the first view "home" rather than all of them on the main page

Comment: here is the plunker that proves this is the solution https://plnkr.co/edit/N1RzdjsebV7Zz9fTGopQ?p=preview